# inline function in an array of functions, good idea for performance?

Tags: c++

The question is in the title but it's not necessarily clear so here's a code example of what I wanted to do:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef void (*functions)(void);

inline void func_A()
{
    std::cout << "I am A !" << std::endl;
}

inline void func_B()
{
    std::cout << "I am B !" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    functions funcs[2] = {func_A, func_B};

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        funcs[i]();

    return 0;
}
```

Is this a good idea compared to the interest of an inline function? Does the compiler handle this well?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What does your profiler say? (In general, function pointers are slow, but this can likely be trivially inlined.) Furthermore, _why_ would you do this? You seem to have the XY-problem: what is the underlying issue you're trying to solve this way?

Comment: Absent optimizations which eliminate the list entirely, a function converted to a function pointer looks exactly the same as an inline function converted to a function pointer. That optimization is *gone* the moment it becomes a pointer.

Comment: First off adding `inline` will not do anything to optimize your code (unless you are using some ancient compiler from decades ago), the compiler will decide for itself whether or not to inline the code. Second the actual optimization being done is essentially copying the code from your function into wherever it is being called from (instead of actually calling a function). By storing the function as a pointer to be called you are potentially making the optimization impossible for the compiler (unless it is smart enough to optimize out your array)

Comment: I was using this type of list in a program and I wanted to know if adding an inline extension had any benefit from a performance point of view, a bit out of curiosity

Comment: @Bigfoot71, No, adding `inline` will not improve performance

Comment: @asimes Thanks ! That's all I wanted to know, thank you very much!

Comment: @Bigfoot71 What list?

Comment: @PaulSanders, I assume Bigfoot71 meant array when they said list

Comment: @asimes Guess so, yes

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes, that's a big misnomer on my part, I'll correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily look at the output of the compilers to see how they handle your code. Here my results for current compilers with `O2` optimization flags, see https://godbolt.org/z/ecjjz88hs.

Current MSVC seems to not optimize the calls at all. It doesn't even unroll the loop and therefore also doesn't determine which functions are actually indirectly called and also consequently can't inline the function calls.

GCC 12.1 does unroll the loop and turns the indirect function calls into direct function calls, but decides not to inline them.

Clang 14.0.0 does unroll the loop and also does inline the two calls to `func_A` and `func_B`.

---

Note that these results can easily change if you change the details of your example, in particular the number of functions called. It is also non-obvious that inlining the function calls is the best decision here. Compared to the `cout <<` statements the function call overhead is negligible.

The `inline` keyword on the functions has no impact on these behaviors. The compilers considered above behave exactly the same with or without it.

---

`inline` may be a hint to the compiler that the function should be considered for inlining. But that is only a very secondary purpose of the keyword. Compilers will consider non-`inline` functions for inlining as well and mainly use internal heuristics to decide whether inlining is appropriate or not.

The main purpose of the `inline` keyword is to be able to define a function in a header file. An `inline` function definition may (in contrast to a non-`inline` one) appear in multiple translation units. (In fact an `inline` function *must* have its definition appear in any translation unit using that function.) This helps inlining by giving the compiler access to the definition of the function directly in the translation unit using it. Without link-time optimization (LTO) compilers can't really inline function calls across translation units.

If a function is meant to be used in only one translation unit anyway, then it should be marked `static`, not `inline`, so that it cannot conflict with other functions of the same name that are meant to be local to another translation unit.

Comment: An handy alternative to the overuse of these keywords may be to enclose functions inside `namespace`s, if it's to avoid name-conflicts across translation units. With link-time optimization enabled, it would appear `inline` has no practical use.

Comment: @Giogre Yes, using unique names with the help of `namespace`s is of course also important. But I would still mark functions that are meant to be local to a `.cpp` file as `static` or rather (equivalently) put them in an unnamed namespace. `inline` is still useful with LTO because it allows defining functions in header files instead of having to decide on one source file. Sometimes this is also required, e.g. `constexpr` functions must be defined in the translation unit where they are used in constant expressions (and therefore `constexpr` implies `inline` on a function).

Comment: Yes, in the case of functions inside headers, modern compilers pretty much decide by themselves  what to inline, save, I think, if a programmer directly removes all optimizations. I have read `inline` is actually necessary for static class data members defined in a header file.